# Run-Time error: 1004 Unable to get the ListIndex property of the ListBox Class

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a very old Excel spreadsheet within a macro in it.

Usage is: start the spreadsheet, push button, select a few other spreadsheets, complete copy and paste in one spreadsheet file.

It works with Office Excel 2007, but not with Office 2013.

When the macro starts, once the files to be appended have been selected, Excel reports:

> Run-Time error: 1004
>   Unable to get the ListIndex property of the ListBox Class

then, when I click on debug, it mark this VBA row in yellow:

```
Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(wbLauncher.Worksheets("config").Cells(Worksheets("config").Range("Program1").Row - 1 + shtActive.Shapes(1).ControlFormat.ListIndex, Worksheets("config").Range("Program1").Column), , True)
```

edit adding the whole code

```css
Sub btnSelectData()
Dim fd As FileDialog, shtActive As Worksheet, fItem As Variant, cID As Integer, rID As Integer
Set shtActive = ActiveSheet
shtActive.Range("D:D").ClearContents
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
fd.InitialFileName = Worksheets("config").Range("dataPath")
fd.Show
cID = Worksheets("GUI").Range("Data1").Column
rID = Worksheets("GUI").Range("Data1").Row
For Each fItem In fd.SelectedItems
    shtActive.Cells(rID, cID) = fItem
    rID = rID + 1
Next
End Sub

Public Sub LoadData(ByVal fName As String)
Dim shtActive As Worksheet, wbData As Workbook
Set shtActive = ActiveSheet
shtActive.Cells(1, 1).Select
If fName <> "" Then
    Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(fName, , True)
    If wbData.Worksheets.Count < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data found in " & fName
    Else
        wbData.Worksheets(1).Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        shtActive.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        shtActive.Cells(1, 1).Select
    End If
    Selection.Clear
    wbData.Close
End If
End Sub

Sub btnLaunch()
Dim wbLauncher As Workbook, shtActive As Worksheet, wbData As Workbook, shtItem As Worksheet
Set wbLauncher = ActiveWorkbook
Set shtActive = ActiveSheet
Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(wbLauncher.Worksheets("config").Cells(Worksheets("config").Range("Program1").Row - 1 + shtActive.Shapes(1).ControlFormat.ListIndex, Worksheets("config").Range("Program1").Column), , True)
For Each shtItem In wbData.Worksheets
    If UCase(Left(shtItem.Name, 5)) = "DATA_" Then
        shtItem.Activate
        LoadData wbLauncher.Worksheets("GUI").Cells(wbLauncher.Worksheets("GUI").Range("Data1").Row - 1 + Val(Right(shtItem.Name, Len(shtItem.Name) - 5)), wbLauncher.Worksheets("GUI").Range("Data1").Column)
    End If
Next
wbData.Worksheets(1).Activate
Application.WindowState = xlNormal
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you post more code, I'm seeing variables but I don't know what they are or how they are set. Also it appears there is a shape object on your sheet, what is that?

Comment: ok, I added the whole code

Comment: So far I've only managed to reproduce the error if I set the listbox on the worksheet to allow multiple selections, (either extend or multi), the listindex returns the index of a selected item in a listbox, apparently it cannot handle multiple selections.

Comment: if I use the same spreadsheet onto a Excel 2007 works as well, how can be ?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

I've added a loop which goes through the listbox and checks if it is selected, if it is it executes the code as before but then continues until all listbox items are checked.

```
Sub btnLaunch()
    Dim wbLauncher As Workbook, shtActive As Worksheet, wbData As Workbook, shtItem As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set wbLauncher = ActiveWorkbook
    Set shtActive = ActiveSheet

    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized

    For i = 1 To shtActive.ListBoxes(1).ListCount
        If shtActive.ListBoxes(1).Selected(i) Then
            Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(wblauncer.Worksheets("Config").Cells(Worksheets("confige").Range("Program1") - 1 + i, Worksheets("Config").Range("Program1").Column), , True)
            For Each shtItem In wbData.Worksheets
                If UCase(Left(shtItem.Name, 5)) = "DATA_" Then
                    shtItem.Activate
                    LoadData wbLauncher.Worksheets("GUI").Cells(wbLauncher.Worksheets("GUI").Range("Data1").Row - 1 + Val(Right(shtItem.Name, Len(shtItem.Name) - 5)), wbLauncher.Worksheets("GUI").Range("Data1").Column)
                End If
            Next shtItem
        wbData.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Next i
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
End Sub
```

### End of edit

---

You must set the selection type of your listbox on the worksheet to "Single", the reason you're getting the error is because currently it is set to either "Multi" or "Extend". You can right click the listbox and click on "Format Control"

All the information I found, states that the `FormatControl.ListIndex` property does not work when the selection type is set to anything but "Single"

Looking at your code, it would seem illogical to select multiple lines anyway. The `Workbook.Open` can only open one file at the time. You can of course incorporate it in a loop to open multiple workbooks, but that is not the case.

With the line that the debugger highlights:

```
Set wbData = Workbook.Open("Filename as String", ,"Read only")
```

The Filename in your code is set as follows:

```
bLauncher.Worksheets("config").Cells(Worksheets("config").Range("Program1").Row - 1 + shtActive.Shapes(1).ControlFormat.ListIndex, Worksheets("config").Range("Program1").Column)
```

The Code refers to a worksheet called "Config". On this worksheet a cell is referred to by the

```
Cells(Rowindex, Columnindex)
```

The Row- and Columnindex are numbers which refer to the rownumber and column the cell is on. e.g. cell `A2` is `Cells(2, 1)` cell `E34` is ` Cells(34,5)

You're code is setting the Rowindex as follows

```
Worksheets("config").Range("Program1").Row - 1 + shtActive.Shapes(1).ControlFormat.ListIndex
```

This bit refers to a named range named "Pgrogam1" on the worksheet "Config" the `.row` returns the rownumber this range is on. 1 is then subtracted from this number and then the listindex of the selection is added to arrive at the cell which holds the filename which corresponds to the selection in the listbox.

Multiple selections in the listbox would mean that you're trying to open multiple cells and with your current code that is impossible, even under office 2007.

Comment: all right, thanks a lot of your time and your explanation but... I have an old desktop with Excel 2007 where same file works as well Office will be either upgraded there to O2013
what I shall do then ?
by the way the workbook is created to open multiple spreadheets... is made for this purpose
sorry, I'm not a VBA guru, that's whjy I asked help here
:-)

Comment: That's fine, I in now way claim to be an Excel guru either. I'm still learning every day, before you upgrade, could you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853498/controlformat-listindex-runtime-error-excel-2007) question, I asked it because I'm still trying to figure the underlying issue. In the mean time, I'll try and come up with a loop that will allow to open multiple workbooks based on your ListBox Selections.

Comment: all right thanks for your help, in the meanwhile we're using my personal laptop with excel 2007, is not acceptable but it is the only way I have at the moment, thank you

Comment: oh well, it seems that this is an unsolvable problem, it is odd, I did another test, installe Office 2007 from a scratch just as FULL options, and the spreadsheet file works fine, I try the same on a O2013 ( full install either ) and reports 1004 error.... this is a nonsense